# How to filter an array based on property value and return array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects with the `name` and `isPinned` keys. I would like to store only the country name in a new array based on what `isPinned` is. For example, if Australia and China have `isPinned` as true, then the new array would be:

`const countriesFiltered = ["Australia", "China"]`

```
const countries = [
    { name: "Australia", isPinned: true },
    { name: "China", isPinned: true },
    { name: "India", isPinned: false },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would `.filter` by `isPinned` and then `.map` by `name`

```
const namesOfPinnedCountries = countries
    .filter(it => it.isPinned)
    .map(it => it.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.filter()` and `.map()` is the classical solution, but you can also do it with `.reduce()`:

```js
const countries = [
{ name: "Australia", isPinned: true },
{ name: "China", isPinned: true },
{ name: "India", isPinned: false },
  ];

const res=countries.reduce((a,c)=>
  c.isPinned?[...a,c.name]:a,[]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const countries = [
    { name: "Australia", isPinned: true },
    { name: "China", isPinned: true },
    { name: "India", isPinned: false },
];
const countriesFiltered = countries
    .flatMap(i => i.isPinned ? i.name : []);
    
console.log(countriesFiltered);
```